# How to import and array of data?

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I'm trying to import many files which have the same name "x.data", but they end with a extension "x_code1.data".

I was trying to import all files with the routine:

```
Importdata1 = 
Import["x_code1.dat", "Table"];
```

But I want to have an array with all the codes, something similar to:

```
For i = {1,4,7,10}

Importalldata[i] = 
Import["x_code[i].dat", "Table"];
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: `Import[#, "Table"] & /@ 
 Table["xcode" <> IntegerString[i, 10] <> ".data", {i, 1, 10}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the list of filenames using [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)

```
Table[
 StringTemplate["FileNameBase``.extension"][k]
 , {k, 5}
 ]
(* {"FileNameBase1.extension", "FileNameBase2.extension", \
"FileNameBase3.extension", "FileNameBase4.extension", \
"FileNameBase5.extension"} *)
```

Now we apply this to your case

```
alldata = Table[
  Import[
   StringTemplate["x_code``.dat"][k]
   , "Table"]
  , {k, {1,4,7,10}}
  ]
```