# Generate a list of variable names

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

How can I generate a list of variable-names like {p0, p1, p2, p3} etc...

I tried:

```
mylist = p # &@Range[1, 4]
```

But then the result is:

> {p, 2 p, 3 p, 4 p}

Comment: you could do something like `ToExpression[StringJoin["p",ToString[#]]]&/@Range[4]` but in general it is not recommended; the usual recommendation is to use indexed variables ie use `p/@Range[4]`; [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94294/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-well-behaved-indexed-variable-subscript-toexpr) seems relevant; on a different note, perhaps [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unique.html) is helpful, also

Comment: You _could_ use `Table[StringTemplate["p``"][i], {i, 5}]` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176407/106)) or maybe `Table["p" <> IntegerString[i, 10], {i, 1, 5}]`.  But, as user42582 points out, it is better to consider using indexed variables.  For example: `Array[p, 5]` (but avoid subscripted variable names, as in `Array[Subscript[a, #] &, {5}]`, as (IMO at least) these can cause problems).